# Can preg_match be broken? /<(\w+)>/ empty result in $match[0]

Tags: php, preg-match

This is my two lines code:

`preg_match('/<(\w+)>/', "<word>", $match);
 var_export($match);`

And the output:

`array (
  0 => '',
  1 => 'word',
)`

Why `$match[0]` is empty when it should contains the whole matched string?

Thanks!

Comment: because in html anything enclosed in `<` is treated as a tag. Check the page contents not the rendering.

Comment: Oh! I'm so **stupid**, sorry and thanks bro!

Comment: `$match = array_map('htmlentities', $match)` - :-D

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response from zerkms:

"because in html anything enclosed in < is treated as a tag. Check the page contents not the rendering."

**Edit:**

Always remember to correctly encode your content before render it in html:

`preg_match('/<(\w+)>/', "<word>", $match);
htmlentities( var_export($match) );`

This is a very important security concern.